# AWS go SDK S3 upload with public access

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've been trying to upload an object to S3 with public access but I haven't been able to do it.

I am getting this error: `InvalidArgument: Argument format not recognized status code: 400`

Here is my code:

```
bucketName := "test-bucket"
key2 := "test.zip"
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: &bucketName,
    Key:    &key2,
    Body:   response.Body,
    GrantRead: aws.String("uri:http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"),
}

sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

_, err = uploader.Upload(upParams)
```

Answer (score 15):

Try ACL : "public-read" instead

```
bucketName := "test-bucket"
key2 := "test.zip"
upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: &bucketName,
    Key:    &key2,
    Body:   response.Body,
    ACL: "public-read",
}

sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

_, err = uploader.Upload(upParams)
```

Comment: As of Sep. 2020, I believe the SDK has changed to expect passing `aws.String(...)` in many cases. So here it would be `aws.String("public-read")`

Comment: thanks Brian.  I don't have time to test this (I'm sure you are correct) so I'll just leave it as an upvoted comment